# How can I link the navigation bar to an activity in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-activity

My app has a navigation drawer implemented, when I clicked on the buttons, they work and take me to a fragment. Here's the code in the main activity that linked the button to the fragment:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_storyboard) {

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Storyboard");
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new HomeFragment()).commit();

    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_mission) {

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Missions");
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new SettingsFragment()).commit();
        
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("All Missions");
       // moveToNewActivity(); //the problem this method does not work might be it's not going from a fragment to an activity
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new ProfileFragment()).commit();

    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_signout) {

        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        Intent loginActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(loginActivity);
        finish();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;

}
```

^Please excuse my unmatched IDs and names

So I want to link the buttons directly to an activity and not a fragment, I tried to write a method that's commented out in the code above:

```
private void moveToNewActivity () {

    Intent i = new Intent(this, MissionActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    ((Activity) this).overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

}
```

But that crashes my app. I also tried switching out "this" to "getActivity()", but it shows that this method does not exist. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: try using getApplicationContext() or getContext()

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio` as that tag is for questions/problems related to the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question and has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: In what class is this code? If this code isn't in an `Activity`, then you will need access to a `Context`. Does this code get a `Context` in the constructor?